# CSS flex: distribute items over 2 rows but evenly

Tags: css, flexbox

i am working on a quick links section

```
<div class="quick-links">

    <a href="#">Kashw Kilsooe</a>
    <a href="#">Kistoork Oltor</a>
    <a href="#">Iskot Mroow</a>
    <a href="#">Kiwlauqo Koela</a>
    <a href="#">Lipelaer</a>
    <a href="#">Loperituroep Luspeorlsi</a>
    <a href="#">Jepilozituro</a>
    <a href="#">Powlerizsty Powl</a>

</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
<style>

    .quick-links {
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .quick-links a {
        flex-grow: 4;
        margin:.5em .25em;
        background:#abd734;
        font-size:110%;
        color:#353433;
        padding:.5em;
        text-align:center;
    }

</style>
```

I want the links to be distributed evenly... but on large screens i get this:
[image]

The last image on large screens has 100% percent width. this does not look good and i want to have at least two or three items on each line (on large screens, dependent on the width of the other items and the parent element).

Like this (now only on smaller screens):
[image]

here is my pen:
https://codepen.io/kili123/pen/eYWyVdX

Comment: If you want a group to go to the next line you probably have to wrap them in a parent element, or create media queries

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your issue in a couple of ways, as outlined below.

This first would be using the `max-width` property on your quicklinks `<a>` tags. This would create the following result:

```css
.quick-links {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
    
 .quick-links a {
    flex-grow: 4;
    margin:.5em .25em;
    background:#abd734;
    font-size:110%;
    color:#353433;
    padding:.5em;
    text-align:center; 
    
    /* Added styles */
    max-width: 75%;
 }
 
 
/* Added styles */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .quick-links a {
      max-width: 50%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .quick-links a {
      max-width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="quick-links">

    <a href="#">Kashw Kilsooe</a>
    <a href="#">Kistoork Oltor</a>
    <a href="#">Iskot Mroow</a>
    <a href="#">Kiwlauqo Koela</a>
    <a href="#">Lipelaer</a>
    <a href="#">Loperituroep Luspeorlsi</a>
    <a href="#">Jepilozituro</a>
    <a href="#">Powlerizsty Powl</a>
    
    <!-- Showing what happens if you have lots of text -->
    <a href="#">Powlerizsty Powl Powlerizsty Powl Powlerizsty Powl</a>
</div>
```

The drawback to this is that you are telling the element to never be wider than 25% of the container at a larger breakpoint. This means that should the element have longer text, it would enlarge the height of the element.

The other way of tackling the problem would be to change the `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow` properties of the links as follows:

```css
.quick-links {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
    
 .quick-links a {
    /* Added styles */
    flex: auto 0 1; 
 
    margin:.5em .25em;
    background:#abd734;
    font-size:110%;
    color:#353433;
    padding:.5em;
    text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="quick-links">

    <a href="#">Kashw Kilsooe</a>
    <a href="#">Kistoork Oltor</a>
    <a href="#">Iskot Mroow</a>
    <a href="#">Kiwlauqo Koela</a>
    <a href="#">Lipelaer</a>
    <a href="#">Loperituroep Luspeorlsi</a>
    <a href="#">Jepilozituro</a>
    <a href="#">Powlerizsty Powl</a>
    
    <!-- Showing what happens if you have lots of text -->
    <a href="#">Powlerizsty Powl Powlerizsty Powl Powlerizsty Powl</a>
</div>
```

The downside to this method, however, is that your items no longer fill the full width of the container due to the nature of the `flex-wrap: wrap` property combined with the `flex-grow: 0` property that is set within the line:

```
flex: auto 0 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use media Query  for small device and change flex-wrap

```css
  
        .quick-links {
            display:flex;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
        }
          
      @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
             .quick-links {
                flex-wrap: wrap;
             }  
           }
            
            .quick-links a {
                flex-grow: 4;
                margin:.5em .25em;
                background:#abd734;
                font-size:110%;
                color:#353433;
                padding:.5em;
                text-align:center;
            }
```

```html
    
        <div class="quick-links">
    
            <a href="">Kashw Kilsooe</a>
            <a href="">Kistoork Oltor</a>
            <a href="">Iskot Mroow</a>
            <a href="">Kiwlauqo Koela</a>
            <a href="">Lipelaer</a>
            <a href="">Loperituroep Luspeorlsi</a>
            <a href="">Jepilozituro</a>
            <a href="">Powlerizsty Powl</a>
    
        </div>
```